# Video is not rendered in accord videoSourcePlayer control

Tags: c#, accord.net

I have an accord videoSourcePlayer control in my form.Why is it that it is not rendering the video that I select? Please see my code below:

```
// Open video file using DirectShow
        private void openVideoFileusingDirectShowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // create video source
                FileVideoSource = new FileVideoSource(openFileDialog.FileName);

                // open it
                sourceInitialiization = true;
                OpenVideoSource(FileVideoSource);
            }
        }

// Open video source
        private void OpenVideoSource(IVideoSource source)
        {
            // set busy cursor
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            // close previous video source
            CloseVideoSource();

            // start new video source
            videoSourcePlayer.VideoSource = new AsyncVideoSource(source);
            videoSourcePlayer.Start();

            // reset statistics
            statIndex = statReady = 0;

            // start timers
            timer.Start();
            alarmTimer.Start();
            //alarmTimer1.Start();

            videoSource = source;

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
```

In my laptop where I initially coded this program, this works perfectly, but if I transfer it to another machine, say a desktop or another laptop, the code doesn't work anymore. It runs but it doesn't render the video and there is not error detected in the debugger too.
I tried downloading a sample video project from accord framework but I still couldn't get it to play a video on the desktop except on my laptop. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you subscribed to the NewFrameReceived event?